# The maximum number of columns per sheet was exceeded

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

When i tried to open some MS Excel files in LibreOffice Calc i get this warn. I searched solution of this issue but i did not find useful things. How can i increase number of  column limit?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

1. `Options...` ▸ `LibreOffice` ▸ `Advanced` ▸ `Optional Features` ▸ `Enable experimental features (may be unstable)`
2. Restart LibreOffice
3. `Options...` ▸ `LibreOffice Calc` ▸ `Defaults` ▸ `New Spreadsheet` ▸ `Enable very large spreadsheets (16m rows, 16384 cols)`

Comment: Options is in the tools tab.

Comment: In Libreoffice Calc v6.4 (from 2020), there is no `New Spreadsheet` ▸ `Enable very large spreadsheets` in the Options dialog. Seems to be v7+ only (?) Haven't checked yet.

Answer (score 2):

> How can i increase number of column limit?

The maximum number of columns per sheet is 1024. If the file from Excel you are trying to open has more than 1024 columns, you won't be able to open it. Currently, there is no workaround to increase the number.

[Other limits](https://libreofficehelp.com/maximum-number-rows-columns-cells-libreoffice-calc/) in Libre Office Calc include:

> LibreOffice Calc has below limits for number of rows, columns and cells that it can handle.

> - Maximum number of Columns per worksheet = 1024 (Col A to AMJ).
> - Maximum number of Rows per worksheet = 1048576 (2^20).
> - Maximum number of cells per worksheet = 1,073,741,824 (2^30).
> - Maximum number of characters in one cell = 32767
> - Maximum number of worksheets in a workbook = 10000

[Version 7](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/7.0#Support_for_very_large_spreadsheets) might support it when it is released. Try the prerelease of version 7 and enable support as indicated on the link.

Answer (score 0):

The popup seems to be related to the processing of the ODF format version "1.3 Extended".

In my case I have an ods file created with an older LibreOffice version and I also get this popup. However, after switching Calc to the previous ODF format version 1.3 the popup disappeared:

`Tools -> Options -> Load/Save -> General -> Default File Format and ODF Settings -> ODF format version`